# Can a parent class have a field, whose generic type is that of the current descendant?

Tags: java, generics

Two classes:

- `Entity` (abstract class)
- `Animal` (child of `Entity`)

An interface:

```java
public interface IPositionObserver<T extends Entity> {
    public void onPositionChange(T entity, Vector2 from, Vector2 to);
}
```

I would like `Entity` to implement this interface, so all descendants of it can be automatically observed, however I want the `T` to be resolved to the most derived class. I.e. if I create an instance of `Animal`, I want it the function to look like `onPositionChange(Animal entity, Vector2 from, Vector2 to)`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

```
class Parent<C extends Parent<C>> {
  C field;
}

class Child extends Parent<Child> {
}
```

`Child.field` is of type `Child`.

Comment: Though people will recognise this pattern and understand that they are supposed to do `extends Parent<TheSameClassAsTheOneThatYouAreWriting>`, it is important to note that this is not enforced by the compiler. For example, `class Foo extends Parent<Child>` compiles.

Comment: @Sweeper and, indeed, if you extended `Child`, say `class Grandchild extends Child`, then `Grandchild` is a `Parent<Child>`, not a `Parent<Grandchild>`.